# docker service does not start after creating daemon.json

Tags: docker, debian, virtual-machine, daemon

Following error message appears when doing the steps below

```
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2017-08-30 09:21:52 CEST; 13s ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 11581 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 11581 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
      CPU: 28ms

Aug 30 09:21:52 debian systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 30 09:21:52 debian systemd[1]: docker.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Aug 30 09:21:52 debian systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
Aug 30 09:21:52 debian systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Aug 30 09:21:52 debian systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Aug 30 09:21:52 debian systemd[1]: docker.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 30 09:21:52 debian systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 30 09:22:00 debian systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Aug 30 09:22:00 debian systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Aug 30 09:22:00 debian systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

- I created a fresh Ubuntu 64bit VM on VirtualBox.
- Then I used the install script to install docker: https://get.docker.com/
- After the installation went successful I tried to configure the daemon to `10.0.2.15:2375` so I can forward it to my Host OS
- I ran `nano /etc/docker/daemon.json` to create the file
- I pasted following example into it

  `{
    "debug": true,
    "tls": false,
    "tlscert": "/var/docker/server.pem",
    "tlskey": "/var/docker/serverkey.pem",
    "hosts": ["tcp://10.0.2.15:2375"]
  }`
- then I ran `service docker restart`
- running `service docker status` shows me the message above

Comment: try running `/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd://` as root manually and check any error messages from there

Comment: `unable to configure the Docker daemon with file /etc/docker/daemon.json: the following directives are specified both as a flag and in the configuration file: hosts: (from flag: [fd://], from file: [tcp://10.0.2.15:2375])` Now I know the issue but how to remove the flag? I can't find the configuration for this.

Comment: Try in `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service`

Comment: In a root shell `dockerd -H tcp://10.0.2.15:2375`, also try `ifconfig` and see if the interface even has the correct address or not?

Comment: the in `docker.service` worked! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Check the docker version of your machine by

```
docker --version
```

I was facing the same issue, and it got solved after upgrading the docker to latest version which is available.

Even the documentation available on docker's official website have not mentioned anything like that.

Once you upgrade docker , Restart the docker by

```
systemctl restart docker
```

The error will be gone, and new changes will start reflecting